# iterm2: how to send a new line using vi special char?

Tags: vim, iterm2

In iterm2 profile, I want to define key mapping control+4 as the code of

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

So that in ipython I could just press Ctrl+4 to send these command. But how to define it? I am using "send Text with  'vim' Special char", but no matter use "\n" or "\r" as a new line, it doesn't work.

e.g is:

```
%load_ext autoreload\n%autoreload 2
```